# Binary tree with structs (in C)

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree of structs. The struct is

```
    typedef struct hashtag {
        char *name;
        int acc;
    } *Item;
```

The nodes are organized by the string. I want to print the node which has the highest acc but is first in alphabetical order.
My code so far:

```
    Item search_max(link h) {
        int max;
        char *word;
        Item hashtag = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        Item left = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        Item right = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        hashtag = h->item;
        max = h->item->acc;
        word = h->item->name;
        if (h == NULL) 
            return 0;
        left = search_max(h->l);
        if (max == left->acc && less(left->name, word))
            word = left->name;
        if (max < left->acc){
            max = left->acc;
            word = left->name;
        }
        right = search_max(h->r);
        if (max == right->acc && less(right->name, word))
            word = right->name;
        if (max < right->acc){
            max = right->acc;
            word = right->name;
        }
        hashtag->acc = max;
        hashtag->name = word;
        return hashtag;
    }
```

h is the head of the tree and less is

```
    #define less(a,b) (strcmp(a,b) < 0)
```

and link is

```
    typedef struct node{
        Item item;
        struct node *l;
        struct node *r;
    } *link;
```

It gives a segmentation fault(core dumped). Previously I tried the same code without allocating memory for hashtag, left or right (same error).

Comment: `Item hashtag = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        Item left = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        Item right = (Item)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtag));
        hashtag = h->item;` You are leaking memory here. **and** : `Item search_max(link h) {` what is *link* ?

Comment: @joop I edited my question and now I also have the code of link. How can I fix the problem of memory leaking? Sorry for the question but I'm new at this

Comment: Note: if your tree is sorted on item->name, the only way to find the element with the max(item->acc) is by inspecting **all** nodes-->>items. (or: by first re-sorting the tree on item->acc) (which is what you attempt to do, BTW)

Comment: but I'm inspecting all nodes. I had a similar function just to find the max of the acc and it worked. It was when I tried to find the name that it stopped working

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger...

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating memory for the Item pointers and then overwriting the pointers.
You have two choices: You could use item values or you could use pointers correctly:

For the first choice you would have to remove the * from the Item typedef and change all usages of Items. For the second choice (which is easier in this case) you should remove all mallocs from search_max. Then use:

```
Item left = search_max(h->l);
...
```

Note that you can **not locally** check the second criteria (lexicographic string order). Instead you again have two choices: collect all entries that have the highest acc-value into another collection, then when you are done with the tree go through that collection to find that single string. Second choice: recursively pass info through all calls to search_max - the info is the current string and its acc-value.

Answer (score 0):

The result is either the item in the current node, or an item under its left- or right subtree. Divide and conquer: (I removed the typedeffed pointers for clarity and sanity)

NOTE: there are no malloc()s needed. You are only examining an *existing* tree, not adding anything to it.

---

```
struct item {
        char *name;
        int acc;
        };

struct node {
        struct item *item;
        struct node *left, *right;
        };

int items_cmp( struct item *one, struct item *two)
{
if (one->acc < two->acc) return -1; /* two is better */
if (one->acc > two->acc) return 1;  /* one is better */
return strcmp(one->name, two->name);
}

struct item * find_max( struct node *np)
{
struct item *ret, *sub;

if (!np) return NULL; /* stop the recursion ! */

ret = np->item;
sub = find_max(np->left);
if ( sub && items_cmp(ret, sub) > 0)
        ret = sub;

sub = find_max(np->right);
if ( sub && items_cmp(ret, sub) > 0)
        ret = sub;

return ret;
}
```